# How to setup the page content for Twitter Bootstrap pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on changing a web application for a client to use Twitter Bootstrap instead of YUI and have a question relating to Bootstrap Pagination. I have looked at the documentation for pagination here:

http://cssdeck.com/item/271/twitter-bootstrap-pagination-and-pager

but this only seems to show how to create a pagination header, not how to setup the actual page content for individual pages. Does anyone have a link to a more complete example of pagination using Twitter Bootstrap?

I was actually hoping for a jquery plugin that would allow me to load all the content pages in div's and then have the pagination header automatically generated for the number of pages found. Does Bootstrap pagination not do this? If not, does anyone know of a plugin that is based on Bootstrap that does do this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VHZqj/6/show might help! :) just thought of updating.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should try Jquery DataTables http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap .

Live Demo : http://datatables.net/media/blog/bootstrap/

### Updated Answer

Jquery Datatable - Bootstrap 3 (With Pagination)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>DataTables Bootstrap 3 example</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dataTables.bootstrap.css">

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10-dev/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#example').dataTable();

        } );
    </script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">

 <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center"> 4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeC">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 5.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5</td>
        <td class="center">C</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 5.5</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center">5.5</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 6</td>
        <td>Win 98+</td>
        <td class="center">6</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
        <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
        <td class="center">7</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even gradeA">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>AOL browser (AOL desktop)</td>
        <td>Win XP</td>
        <td class="center">6</td>
        <td class="center">A</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
  </table>

 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

You can download the files from here: https://copy.com/ViElPNKAUNCR

Comment: black_belt - can you please let me know what all resources are needed for datatable pagination? I downloaded the zip file from http://datatables.net/download/ and included dataTables.bootstrap.css, dataTables.bootstrap.js, jquery.dataTables.min.js, jquery-DT-pagination.js. The pagination icons appear but couldn't still see the paginations though.It shows Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries even though I have entries in the datatable

Comment: Did you download the files from the link I gave above? If not please download and check the source code, that should give you a clear idea.